# Terminate all ECS tasks before new deployment

Tags: amazon-ecs

If an ECS task runs in multiple instances, the rolling deployment methods usually terminate tasks one by one and replace it with a newer version (newer task definition), in order to maximize uptime.

But we have some containers that may make schema upgrades on first-run (as an example), and here we never want old versions of a container to run at the same time as newer versions.

Another example is coupled data formats, that a new front-end talks to a new API. We'd rather have a moment of downtime than have old front-ends talk to new APIs, or new front-ends talk to old APIs.

ECS doesn't seem to provide a deployment strategy that terminates all instances of a task before starting to roll out new ones.

Before I roll some bash script that reduces task counts to 0 prior to an update and returns it to its original value, does anyone know if AWS provides a way to cleanly drain a service of tasks before rolling out a new task definition?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar scenario I would do it as follows.

I would add my pipeline (if using a stack code) a CodeDeploy step and set the traffic to "All-at-once", this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/%20AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-bluegreen.html) can start to direct you something.

In case I was unable to work with the stack code, I would create a lambda, which would be triggered by the pipeline, a step before the deploy, this lambda could interact with the ECS, resetting the tasks to receive the new version of the application, but in this situation, a downtime will be felt, of at least 2 ~ 5 minutes, depending on how your application is optimized. You can see a little more about the lib that will allow you to do this [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html).